# Packery horizontal layout

Tags: github, bower, packery

I am using the awesome script Packery. (https://github.com/metafizzy/packery)
However the script is for vertical layouts and not horizontal.

2 weeks ago a user modified the original version, so it's possible to have a horizontal layout.
(https://github.com/metafizzy/packery/pull/76)

The problem is that it's uncompiled. And I don't have a clue how to compile all the files + dependencies.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I have successfully compiled it!
For the people in need:
http://pastebin.com/wZ3hbk49

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled it all and now it's working.
Full compiled code for the people who want to have horizontal packery.
http://pastebin.com/wZ3hbk49

Answer (score 1):

Packery now support [horizontal layouts with `isHorizontal: true`](http://packery.metafizzy.co/options.html#ishorizontal)